# How can I make each child of component has a state? react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my project, there are HomeIndexView and table component. So, when a user logs in to his account, in HomeIndexView, it shows all tables in the database. What I want to do is that make each table have a state so that it changes color of depends on its state(depends on child's state)... How can I do this?

My table component has a state like below.

```
const initialState = {
 allTables: [],
 showForm: false,
 fetching: true,
 formErrors: null,
};
```

EDIT ---1

HomeIndexView

```
class HomeIndexView extends React.Component {
 componentDidMount() {
 setDocumentTitle('Table_show');
 }

componentWillunmount() {
 this.props.dispatch(Actions.reset());
}

_renderAllTables() {
 const { fetching } = this.props;

 let content = false;

 if(!fetching) {
   content = (
    <div className="tables-wrapper">
      {::this._renderTables(this.props.tables.allTables)}
    </div>
    );
  }

 return (
   <section>
    <header className="view-header">
      <h3>All Tables</h3>
    </header>
    {content}
  </section>
  );
 }


_renderTables(tables) {
    return tables.map((table) => {
        return <Table
            key={table.id}
            dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
            {...table} />;               
    });
  }

render() {
  return (
    <div className="view-container tables index">
    {::this._renderAllTables()}
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

EDIT--2

```
 _handleClick () {

    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    const data = {
        table_id: this.props.id,

    };

    if (this.props.current_order == null) {

        dispatch(Actions.create(data));

        Object.assign({}, this.state, {
            tableBusy: true
        });
    }

    else{

        this.props.dispatch(push(`/orders/${this.props.current_order}`));
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some code of table homeindexview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state you shared above is part of the **global state** (where tableReducer use) not the table's **component state**, so what you need is to initialize component state in `Table` React component, so that you can check some values to render css differently something like this:

```
import React from "react";

class TableComponent extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setInitialState();
  }

  setInitialState() {
    this.setState({ isWhatever: false });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 classname={this.state.isWhatever ? 'css-class' : 'another-class'}>
            {this.props.id}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, then should I make separate reducer and action for this state ? or can I just add it together with global Table state? and also is it possible to subscribe this state by `store.subscribe(()=>{})`??

Comment: You don't have to do neither reducers or actions as it's React component state not Redux global state. Use React for ephemeral state that doesn't matter to the app globally and doesn't mutate in complex ways. For example, a toggle in some UI element, a form input state. Use Redux for state that matters globally or is mutated in complex ways. For example, cached users, or a post draft. Sometimes you'll want to move from Redux state to React state (when storing something in Redux gets awkward) or the other way around (when more components need to have access to some state that used to be local).

Comment: well, I think i'm misunderstanding redux... what I think is that when I click a table, it changes state so it re-renders different color of table. So I was thinking making an action and reducer to do so...  is it possible without store??

Comment: As it doesn't affect any of the objects in the global state except your component so let's confine this chnge on the React state component, so yes no need for Redux store. That's it!

Comment: I changed table components what you suggested me and it is successful to set state for each table. I added my _handleClick action, so basically, when there is no order, it creates order and redirect. And I want to change state of that table (tableBusy false to true) so it shows different color.. so i tried to change state by  using object assign function like above, but it doesn't change state and color of table.... how should I do this ?? Can't I use object assign to change value of table state?(component state)

Comment: You have to use `this.setState()` rather than `Object.assign()` as the first is overwriting while the second is merging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128519/discussion-between-d-r-and-basim-hennawi).